# A bounded open set that contains infinitely many open sets but not their boundaries?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $V$ be a bounded open set of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ ($n>1$). Can there exists an INFINITE sequence of disjoint open sets $(C_{n})$, all included in the closure of $V$ and such that the boundary of each $C_{n}$ is included in the boundary of $\overline{V}$?

Comment: Trivially if you allow $C_n=V$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. You should have some kind of additional condition (disjoint?) to avoid these cases.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for your remark. I corrected...

Comment: what is an infinite sequence of open sets? Just a countable family?

Comment: Yes, but their number is not finite.

Answer (score 3):

Certainly. Let $C_n$ be the open ball of radius $\frac{1}{2^{n+2}}$, centered along one of the positive coordinate axes a distance $\frac{1}{2^n}$ from the origin. Let $V = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} C_n$. $V$ is bounded by, say, the unit ball of radius 2 centered at the origin; the $C_n$ are open because they are open unit balls; $V$ is open because it is a union of open sets; the $C_n$ are disjoint because $C_n$ and $C_{n+1}$ have centers which are further apart than the sum of their radii; and the boundary of $V$ is precisely the union of the boundaries of the $C_n$.

Comment: But the boundary of  each $C_{n}$ must be in the boundary of the closure of $V$.

Comment: They are. The boundary of $C_n$ is the circle of radius $\frac{1}{2^{n+2}}$ centered a distance $\frac{1}{2^n}$ from the origin. As stated in the answer, the boundary of $V$ (which is the same as the boundary of the closure of $V$) is precisely the union of these circles. Draw a picture in $\mathbb{R}^2$ of the first few $C_n$ to convince yourself.

edit: missed a close-paren which made the sentence confusing

Comment: I don't get it: how come the boundary of $V$ and the boundary of its closure is the same?

Comment: The boundary of a set is defined to be the closure minus the interior. Since $V$ is already open, the boundary of $V$ is $\partial V = \overline{V} \setminus V$. Since $\overline{V}$ is closed with interior $V$, its boundary is $\partial\overline{V} = \overline{V}\setminus V$. Thus, $\partial V = \partial\overline{V}$

Comment: No. The interior of $\overline{V}$ (the closure of $V$) is not $V$. For example, set $V=(-1,0)\cup (0,1)$. Then, the interior of $\overline{V}$ is $(-1,1)$, which is not the same as $V$. Also, the boundary of $V$ is $\lbrace -1,0,1\rbrace$ where as the boundary of $\overline{V}$ is just $\lbrace-1,1\rbrace. $ What you say holds if $V$ is a BALL, not just an open.

Comment: I stand corrected on my claim that the boundary of $V$ and of $\overline{V}$ are the same in general. However, in my specific example, it still holds because in this case, the interior of $\overline{V}$ is equal to $V$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  V = ((0,1) - { 1/n : n in N }) x (0,1) is the open union of a
sequence pairwise disjoint open subsets with the desired property.
Problem.  Show if V is connected then no such sequence will exist.

Comment: But what is the boundary of the closure of $V$?  Isn't it just the square?

Comment: No, that is closure V.  My example works with boundary of V.  It fails with the bounday of the closure.  However if you carefully widened the 1/n lines by a small amount, the example would then hold for the boundary of the closure.